# Mostrar item que no existe en lista Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

queria consultar resulta que tengo una lista:

listPersonas=[{id:1,nombre:'pedro'},
{id:2,nombre:'juan'},]

la cual muestro en un select:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="Codigo">
            <option value="{{persona.id}}" *ngFor="let persona of listPersonas">{{ persona.nombre}}</option>
        </select>
```

resulta que consumo un apiRest el cual me trae el "id", el cual asigno al ngModel para que me muestre el dato.
sin embargo hay ocasiones en que el id no existe dentro de la lista pero me solicitan que si no existe el parametro en la lista que muestre seleccionado el Id.
no se como puedo hacer para que cuando no exista muestre el numero de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta no está muy clara.
Por lo que entendí querés mostrar el id si el nombre no existe, eso podés hacerlo utilizando un ternario

```
<option value="{{persona.id}}" *ngFor="let persona of listPersonas">{{ (persona.nombre ? persona.nombre : persona.id) }}</option>
```

Comment: Si lo usas en el html, incluso en versiones más viejas de angular puedes usar esto: `persona.nombre ?? persona.id` es como un ternario pero cortocircuitado, si existe el nombre lo pondrá, si no pondrá la id. Si quieres usarlo en el  .ts tiene que ser a partir de angular... 11 si no recuerdo mal. Puede que 12 :)

Comment: Hola en efecto si entendiste mi pregunta, quiero mostrar el id cuando el nombre no existe, implemente el ternario como me lo sugeriste pero no funciona

Comment: <select [(ngModel)]="contrato.interventor">
                <option value="{{interventor.CODIGO}}"  *ngFor="let interventor of listInterventor">{{ interventor.CODIGO === contrato.interventor ? interventor.DESCRIPCION : contrato.interventor }}</option>
            </select>

Comment: @WilliamAvella Necesitaría ver el objeto contrato, pero sin eso diría que es porque no encerraste el ternario entre paréntesis
{{ (interventor.CODIGO === contrato.interventor ? interventor.DESCRIPCION : contrato.interventor) }}

Comment: el objeto contrato lo unico que trae es el Id para ser asigando, sin embargo al no encontrar un id con el mismo valor en mi lista me muestra el campo en blanco y necesito mostrar es el id que no encontro